# The type initializer for 'BlogEngine.Core.BlogSettings' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net, blogengine.net

The other day all of a sudden I received the following error in my web.config at the following line in a BlogEngine site I have hosted at Godaddy.

I haven’t touched the site for weeks but of course Godaddy say it’s a problem with my code. I have tried everything I can to fix the error but nothing works. I checked my permissions, I made sure the XML files had not become corrupt, from my end nothing has changed.

I’ve even uploaded the whole site to a new directory but received the same error and the whole site works fine locally on my computer.

```
<add name="XmlMembershipProvider" type="BlogEngine.Core.Providers.XmlMembershipProvider, BlogEngine.Core" description="XML membership provider" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
```

Does anyone know what may have gone wrong here???

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: That's it, no stack trace or anything else! "The type initializer for 'BlogEngine.Core.BlogSettings' threw an exception." on the above line.

Comment: I'd download the full version again and give it another try...

Comment: I've extended it a lot, it would be quicker to build a whole new site without BE involved.

Comment: I wouldn't get disheartened - this is just something flaky :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution was, total re-build in MVC, took me four very intensive days, it looks exactly the same to the user but it’s all mine!

In the 15 years building websites I have gathered one very important piece of knowledge. “Never use somebody else’s code!” It may save you time in the short term but it WILL cause you problems down the track.